# Multiple check boxes toggling back and forth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with two check boxes.

```
   <table id="id1">
        <tr>
            <td> <label class="" for="Otest2" >Test2</label></td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" class="" id="rv" name="Vn" /> </td>
             <td><label class="" for="Otest3" >DV</label></td>
             <td> <input type="checkbox" class="" id="dv" name="Dv" />  </td>          
         </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="button" id="vList" value="Run Report" /></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

Jquery function processing the check boxes is

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#vList").click(function () {
                  if ($('#rv').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'))) {
                      fnloadrv(test);
                  }
                  else if ($('#dv').prop('checked',$(this).is(':checked'))) {
                      fnloaddv();
                  }
             });
```

It works fine only first time. Second itme If I check the box again it wont do anything. I believe it needs to be reset or something.
Please let me know how fix so it can toggle back and forth. Thanks

Comment: Please, describe function fnloadrv and fnloaddv.

Comment: what ate you tring to do ?? this does not make sense

Comment: `$('#rv').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'))` _sets_ the state of the checkbox, it doesn't test it.

Comment: @nnnnnn I am trying to do is that second time when i check box it wont work. It will not toggle back and forth between check boxes. Only first time when I check box it works.

Comment: Yes. Read my previous comment again, and then compare your code to the code in palaѕн's answer. And read [the `.prop()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop) and take note of what it says will happen when you supply two arguments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#vList").click(function () {
                  if ($('#rv').is(':checked')) {
                      //fnloadrv(test);
                      alert('test1');
                  }
                  else if ($('#dv').is(':checked')) {
                    //  fnloaddv();
                       alert('test2');
                  }
             });

   });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hQ5dZ/)**

Answer (score 2):

Here's the correct code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#vList").click(function () {
        if ($('#rv').prop('checked')) {
            fnloadrv(test);
        } else if ($('#dv').prop('checked')) {
            fnloaddv();
        }
    });
});
```

- `$('#rv').prop('checked')` return *true* or *false* based on the `rv` element checked status on `vList` button click.